# Deserialising XML file into a Java object using JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb, xml-deserialization, unmarshalling

I'm completely new to XML serialising and processing. 
I'm working on a project and I have a bunch of XML files I need to read and deserialise into objects. As I've never processed XML files before, I tried reading here on stackoverflow and I came up with some code. Some of it works, some of it doesn't and I can't understand why.

My XML file looks like this (there are more movements, but you get the idea):

```
<MovementCards>
    <MovementCard>
        <movements>
            <int>3</int>
            <int>3</int>
            <int>2</int>
            <int>2</int>
            <int>2</int>
            <int>2</int>
        </movements>
    </MovementCard>
</MovementCards>
```

And these are my classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="MovementCards")
public class MovementCards {
    private List<MovementCard> movementCards;

    @XmlElement(name="MovementCard")
    public List<MovementCard> getMovementCards() {
        return this.movementCards;
    }
    public void setMovementCards(List<MovementCard> movementCards) {
        this.movementCards = movementCards;
    }
}

public class MovementCard extends Card {
    @XmlElement(name="movements")
    private int[] movements = new int[FamilyGameManager.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS];

    public int[] getMovements() {
        return movements.clone();
    }

    public void setMovements(int[] movements) {
        this.movements = movements;
    }
}
```

And finally this is the function I've written:

```
public List<MovementCard> generateMovementCards() {
        List<MovementCard> list = new ArrayList<MovementCard>();
        try {
            File file = new File(MovementCardsFile);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MovementCards.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();


            MovementCards movementCards = (MovementCards) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            list = movementCards.getMovementCards();
        } 
        catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and what specifically isn't working?

Comment: @Jacinda I'm trying to get an object MovementCards with an ArrayList<MovementCard> and each MovementCard needs to have an array of six integers (int[] movements). According to the XML I posted, I should get a List of one MovementCard and this MovementCard's movements should be [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]. I tried debugging this part and it doesn't fill the array at all. It leaves six zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="movements")
@XmlElement(name="int")
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, Blaise! I used your tutorial to marshal my objects into Xml to see what happened and then I adjusted what I had already written. That was very helpful!